# Reading Last Text Row in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table like the below:

```
colX  colY
1      a
1      b
2      c
2      d
2      e
```

I want to remove dupes but keep the last row. So my output should be:

```
colX  colY
1      b
2      e
```

How do I do this? `select distinct colX, colY` doesn't remove dupes.

Comment: How do you know it's the last row?

Comment: What data type is colY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MAX aggregate function and group by colX:

```
select colX, max(colY) as colY from your_table group by colX
```

This will select the colY with highest value for each colX. I'm assuming that by *last text row* you are referring to the highest value if you order colY lexically and that the data type is some kind of `char`and not`text`.

Comment: This only works if the highest value is the MAX, OP doesn't say that.

Comment: @DavidG Indeed, I made an assumption that might not hold.

Comment: @Moosa It does not work on the data type `text`no, I assumed the data type to be `char`or`varchar`

Comment: Thanks guys, this worked. I found the column it was actually ordered by. So I didn't need to use the natural order, which didn't feel right anyway.